# CSS rule has a blank source (in web inspector)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, stylesheet

When I inspect an element, and look at the "Computed" CSS tab, I see a list of properties. If I expand any one property I see something like this:
[image]

Which makes perfect sense: the drop-down shows the styles in which they were overriden, with the top one the "winner". All these styles have a link to the right that will show the source where they were defined.

What perplexes me, with an element that I'm trying to control the width of, but can't seem to find where it is overriden, is a situation like this:
[image]

Note that the top style, that I believe should be the "winner", isn't struck-through, yet the value of the property is very different and there is no source listed to explain this difference. Where is this override coming from?

I have tried reordering my style sheets, styling directly on the HTML element, using `!important` in the relevant CSS selector, respecifying my selector to as specific as you can get, and still I can't take hold of the width property of this table.

I've poured hours into it so any help is appreciated.

I'm using Firefox, and this issue appears in both Firebug and the Firefox web inspector.

Screenshot of relevant table:
[image]

Comment: Show code or url to an example maybe?

Comment: IS it possible the `th` is being stretched by content, or another `th/td` in your table. The 466 may be it's current width, accommodating that table stretching, even if it was defined as 30

Comment: @KyleNeedham I appreciate the interest, but I'm not sure what code I should show, its kind of a systemic thing. There's nothing particular about the CSS code that could create the issue. I could post it if you think that would be helpful, though. Can't post a URL, its for a web interface, not a website.

Comment: @rgthree Yes, it is being stretched by content, I'll edit my post to provide a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely not being overridden, but being forced to be different by way of content. I see you are inspecting a table's `th` cell, which will stretch to accommodate the content within it's column, even if it's width is defined in css.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>30</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>More_than_30!</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
</table>

/* CSS */
th {width:30px; background:#CCC;}
td {width:30px; border:1px solid #CCC;}
```

Here, even though the `th` and `td` cells are given a `width:30px;` that center row's cells' computed widths will be much larger due to the stretching of the data to accommodate the long, non-breaking value. In this case, there is no CSS rule overriding the `30px`.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/kYAG7/

Comment: This helps, thanks. We are using DataTables so a good deal of the styling is happening via the plug-in. This did allow me to take control of the table, however, so I'm grateful.